# Invalid results returning from a multi-table SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have a Database with the following structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMeQP.png

I'm trying to run a select statement, getting information from multiple tables, however it keeps bringing me duplicate results. The statement I'm using is:

```
SELECT StockReceipts.StockID, StockReceipts.Quantity, StockPriceHistory.Price
FROM StockReceipts,StockPriceHistory,Receipts
WHERE (Receipts.ReceiptID = 1) AND (Receipts.OrderDate BETWEEN StockPriceHistory.DateStart AND StockPriceHistory.DateEnd)
```

And the results i'm getting are:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMFOv.png

What I actually want is matching rows from the stockreceipts table,
but with the price for each item of stock (the price that was within the date & time of ordering - OrderDate taken from the Receipts table) as well, taken from the StockPriceHistory table. I don't understand why it's making up duplicate/incorrect rows when there are only two rows in the StockReceipts table for that receipt.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: This query will return Cartesian or Cross-Join result. Use Inner Join to get the matching data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      SR.StockID, 
      SR.Quantity, 
      SPH.Price 
   FROM 
      Receipts R
         JOIN StockReceipts SR
            on R.ReceiptID = SR.ReceiptID
            JOIN StockPriceHistory SPH
               on SR.StockID = SPH.StockID
   WHERE 
          R.ReceiptID = 1
      AND R.OrderDate BETWEEN SPH.DateStart AND SPH.DateEnd
```

You had no JOIN conditions between the tables leaving it a Cartesian result... For every record in one, grabbed entries from all other table rows.